# .htaccess Allow index.php from everywhere, but prevent all other .php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to achieve the following:

I want the index.php file to be accessible for everybody, but prevent access to all other .php files, so only my website can use them.

Right now I have the following rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

My website (example.com) can access and use any of the .php files to work with, but when the .php files are called directy (by entering the url directly like `https://example.com/data/foo.php`), access is denied.

The problem is, that I have an index.php with redirection header (`https://example.com/redirect/index.php?url=...`), and I want to achieve that when this redirect link is used from outside my site (like copy-paste the link to a new tab/browser) it would work.

Right now it says forbidden when I copy-paste that link, and that's because of the above rule. And I want to make it work, but I'm really novice in .htaccess, so I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Any PHP (except index.php) must reside outside of the webroot. Any traffic is routed through index.php

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Unfortunately I can't go on without a modified code. What I have above is also a copy-paste from somewhere. Can you please suggest the modified code?

Comment: Can't answer this is a few words, but it's the technique almost any halfway modern framework would do it. No PHP file except the entry point (index.php) can be called from the browser directly, because every PHP resides outside of the webroot. Any request is sent through index.php, which does all the routing. You need to research this concept yourself, most of all how HTTP works. Only then you will understand, that a URL isn't equal to a file on your server (though it _can_ be mapped directly to a file...)

Comment: @HonkderHase My site is working properly now (as detailed above). It has index.html. But I want to implement a redirect solution with a /redirect/ subfolder and an index.php file in it to redirect urls. For that I need the modification requested above. There are 0 .php files in the root, all of them are in different folders.

Comment: @HonkderHase Or if it's a better solution, I can create a subdomain just for the redirection (`https://redirect.example.com`), so there could be it's own .htaccess files, and only 1 file, an index.php. What do you think? What .htaccess rules whould I need in that case? Thank you.